# How to extract text with math symbols using pytesseract/tesseract version 4.0 (using equ.traineddata). 'equ' is no longer supported

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

How can I use the `tesseract` to extract the mathematical equation?

While reading the image given below:

[image]

after using:

```
img = cv2.imread(IN_PATH+'sample1.png')

pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

I get the result as:

```
'The value of 7/8144 is\n- (a) 20.2 (b) 20.16\n(c) 20.12 (d) 20.4'
```

With the older versions, I could have used

```
config='-l eng + equ'
pytesseract.image_to_string(img,config=config)
```

but the `equ` is no longer supported in the `tesseract 4.0+`.
I have the **equ.traineddata** file too but I do not know how that'll work and when I tried to paste it inside the `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/` it threw an error that it can not be copied.

Please help how can I extract some text with simple mathematics symbols in it.

Comment: Really looking for an answer to this, i found something called "math_ocr" but I have no idea how to install it, here is the origin of that: https://onelinerhub.com/tesseract-ocr/how-can-i-use-tesseract-ocr-to-recognize-math-formulas